# Need help to integrate Griddler without a Sendgrid account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, griddler

I want to integrate Griddler without a Sendgrid account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Griddler works by accepting POST requests to a special path and parsing the parameters into an object that you can operate on.

The parameter mapping happens in [adapters](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler/tree/master/lib/griddler/adapters), a byproduct of which is that you can see all of the supported services in the directory I linked.

If none of those adapters work for your needs, feel free to [write your own](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler#adapters).

So no, you don't need a Sendgrid account to use Griddler, but you do need some sort of service that POSTs to your application in a way that Griddler or an adapter can understand.